# Compute that Galois group $Gal\left(F/\mathbb{Q}\right)$, with $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{4}-2X^{3}-8X-3$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Compute the Galois group $Gal\left(F/\mathbb{Q}\right)$, with $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{4}-2X^{3}-8X-3$

Comment: ...and you've already done...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^{4}-2X^{3}-8X-3=(X-3)(X^3+X^2+3X+1)$.

Then $Gal (F/\mathbb{Q})=Gal (E/\mathbb{Q})$, where $E$ is the splitting field of $X^3+X^2+3X+1$.

Now you can easily solve the exercise proving that an irriducible polynomial with order $p$, where $p$ is a prime , and only two roots in $\mathbb{C}$ has Galois Group $S_p$. (Hint: $S_p$ is generated by a transposition and a p-cycle)

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me? Please

Comment: Can you tell the two roots of $X^3+X^2+3X+1$

Comment: Well, I didn't calculated the two roots of polynomial, i've only looked at the graph of $y=x^3+x^2+3x+1$.

Comment: Can we do the same with $X^4-3X^2+4$? (Compute the Galois group $Gal(F/Q)$, with $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^4-3X^2+4$)?

Comment: Ehm, no. You can use the theorem above only if the degree of polynomial is prime. In this case you can easy check the roots putting $t=X^2$ and solve the problem with explicit calculations.